# Cannot resolve method SetVisibility Int

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Can Somebody help me, I don't know the answer, and I don't Know How to resolve it?

This is My Main Code That I am using:

```
package com.wp.fyriaxis;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.wp.fyriaxis.R.id.textView2;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void klik(View view) {

    textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}}
```

The Error is with textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
I am using Android Studio for the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change visibility on `textView2` resource id instead on `View` object.

You have to use `findViewById` method to find actual view object.

Remove this line from imports:

```
import static com.wp.fyriaxis.R.id.textView2;
```

And use following code:

```
public void klik(View view) {

    View v = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have imported a textview from another library

```
import static com.wp.fyriaxis.R.id.textView2;
```

You have to use `import android.widget.TextView;`

You have to associate the component with an element in your view. Like this.

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

after that you can change the visibility

```
txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

- First :

  `TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);`
- Second :

  `textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`